# UINavigationController embedded in a container view, displays a Table View Controller with wrong size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicontainerview

I'm trying to find a workaround to this situation:
I have a UITabBarController one of its segue is connected to a container view controller (BannerViewController) that I'm using to embed a UINavigationController, the navigation controller pushes other container view controllers (EventListContainerviewController) each of this contains a tableview controller.
Here a screen from my story board
[image]
The problem is that the last container view is displayed in a smaller frame than their containers. It seems that they loose the tabbar space at the bottom.
[image]

I've forced all view controllers, navigation controller and tabbar controller to avoid do not extent their edges and adjust insets.

The color means:

> Red: main view of the BannerContainerViewController 0x7fcc6d38bb00
>   light green : the container view of the BannerContainerViewController
>   0x7fcc6d38b860
>
> Blue: main view of the EventListContainerViewController 0x7fcc6bd7b7c0
>   Orange:  the container view of the EventListContainerViewController
>   0x7fcc6bd7b690

It seems that something changes when the navigation controller add the blue container view reducing its size by the same amount of a tabbar (49pt).
It can be also seen in the recursive description of the view hierarchy:

```
<UIWindow: 0x7fcc6bd5af40; frame = (0 0; 320 568); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fcc6bd4dd80>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7fcc6bd317c0>>
   | <UILayoutContainerView: 0x7fcc6bd671c0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fcc6bd66de0>>
   |    | <UITransitionView: 0x7fcc6bd6a980; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fcc6bd6ace0>>
   |    |    | <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x7fcc6d3a7b20; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fcc6d3a7db0>>
   |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fcc6d38bb00; frame = (0 0; 320 519); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fcc6d38bbd0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fcc6d38b860; frame = (0 0; 320 519); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fcc6d38b930>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UILayoutContainerView: 0x7fcc6d398000; frame = (0 0; 320 519); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fcc6d3a4b50>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fcc6d387670>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UINavigationTransitionView: 0x7fcc6d39cfa0; frame = (0 0; 320 519); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fcc6d39cc40>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x7fcc6bf31230; frame = (0 0; 320 519); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fcc6bf31300>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fcc6bd7b7c0; frame = (0 64; 320 406); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fcc6bd7afe0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fcc6bd7b690; frame = (0 0; 320 406); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fcc6bd7aac0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableView: 0x7fcc6f03c400; frame = (0 0; 320 406); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fcc6bf34aa0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fcc6bf30bc0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 170}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewWrapperView: 0x7fcc6bf35960; frame = (0 0; 320 406); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fcc6bf363e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fcc6bf35ed0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 406}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <EventCell: 0x7fcc6bca2950; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 85; 320 85); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fcc6bca2ca0>>
```

I've tries to use custom segue instead of container view try to forcing the layout, but I guess is a navigation controller fault.
As you can see the banner is not overlapping the view as intended.
[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you check that your viewcontroller has the `Extend Edges UnderBottomBars` checked ?

Comment: sure as I've written in the question

Comment: ops... they all have Extended Edges unchecked

Comment: @las it seems to has fixed the issue. If I set the BannerViewController to extend underbottom bars, frames are correct, but I don't understand why, it seems a trick more than solution

Comment: I can't believe that someone else had this specific problem too, I was having such a hard time with this, really glad I found this post and saw that it was a known issue

Comment: @beno I'm still surprise that is still an issue, i've provided a lot of details to Apple to fix it and it seems they never did.

Answer (score 18):

This issue still exists in iOS 10. A UINavigationController embedded in a container view, which in turn is contained in a UITabBarController, will lay out all views in the navigation stack with extra space for a "phantom" tab bar at the bottom.

The easiest solution is to subclass UINavigationController and return 'nil' from `tabBarController`.

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override var tabBarController: UITabBarController? {
        return nil
    }

}
```

This makes the views in the navigation stack think they don't have a tab bar controller, so they won't leave extra space for it during layout. I haven't noticed any negative side effects from this fix, but obviously the views in this navigation controller's stack will no longer have access to the tab bar controller. If that's a problem, you can use a more generic method to find the tab bar controller (or any "parent" view controller).

For example, if the main view controller for your app is a UITabBarController named "MainViewController", you can extend UIViewController with a convenience method to find it.

```
extension UIViewController {

    func mainViewController() -> MainViewController? {
        var vc: UIViewController? = self
        while !(vc is MainViewController) && vc != nil {
            vc = vc?.parent ?? vc?.navigationController ?? vc?.presentingViewController
        }
        return vc as? MainViewController
    }

}
```

This works because a tab bar controller is the `parent` of its direct child view controllers. The above method works its way up the chain of parent, presenting and nav controllers to eventually reach a child of the tab bar controller, which returns the tab bar controller as its parent.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but I'm very upset that Apple doesn't seem to have any interest in fix it. I suggest you to file bug.

Comment: Well, several hours of pain later I decided to search stack overflow and you solved it for me in a minute. I wish I could give you all the up votes.

Comment: Crazy that this problem is still around in iOS14, glad I found this answer, this was driving me nuts

Answer (score 7):

Turns out that is a UIKit bug, I've filed a radar 19996374.
Here is the explanation:

> When a navigation controller is placed inside of a tab bar controller,
>   responsibility for laying out the content (your) view controller is
>   given fully to the navigation controller.  The tab bar controller
>   sizes the navigation controller's view to match the tab bar
>   controller's view bounds.  In turn, the navigation controller accounts
>   for the tab bar height when laying out the content view controller. 
>   Things break when you inject a view controller between the tab bar
>   controller and the navigation controller.  The tab bar controller sees
>   that the selectedViewController is not a UINavigationController and
>   applies the normal layout rules.  But contained navigation controller
>   sees that its tabBarController property contains a valid
>   UITabBarController instance and assumes that it is still responsible
>   for handling the tab bar height when laying out the content (your)
>   view controller.  The result is that the content view controller is
>   inset by the tab bar height twice, as you have observed

As a workaround

> You can work around this problem by setting the isTranslucent property
>   of the tab bar to YES.  Then, in AFBannerViewController, override
>   -edgesForExtendedLayout to return UIRectEdgeAll.  The AFBannerViewController will now underlap the tab bar (so set the
>   background color to something other than pink) but the navigation
>   controller will apply the proper inset to the content view controller.

Comment: To this day, this bug still exists (testing with iOS 9, Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2). Translucent + background color on the view of the Tab bar + edgesForExtendedLayout to .All makes everything work again. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately my bug is till in "require Further Info" even if I sent a small project showing the issue.

Comment: This solution works however I didn't need to override edgesForExtendedLayout.

Answer (score 3):

Did encounter the exact same problem, and found your post.

Actually, I managed to fix it using another method.

My top, leading and trailing constraints for the container view are bounds to the safe area, **BUT**, the bottom one is set to the superview (See attached screenshot)

The trick was to play with the Extend Edges configuration, and set "Under Opaque bars" to **true**, and voila.

I hope it will help other people.

Regards

[image]

[image]